# Jekyll include new sections on a post layout dynamically?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, jekyll, liquid

I've just created a portfolio collection in Jekyll and I've managed to include extra **html sections** on my **`single-project.html`** layout with a simple Liquid syntax.

Those extra html sections came to the rescue so that a single project's page contents would not explicit have to reside within a unique container/wrapper defined for the `{{ content }}` variable.

So (visually speaking) I can put any html stuff within a `<section></section>` and style it accordingly in a way the `single-project.html` layout can be enriched with fullwidth container/elements and so on. However, I'm stuck with the possibility of injecting fullwidth contents only above and bellow the {{ content }} variable.

Would there be a workaround to achieve a dynamic layout structure to include sections on a page in Jekyll?

---

In a **project.md** document

For each single project I want to have extra html sections, I define in the document's front-matter the names of the html files I'd `{% include %}` in a `single-project.html` layout.

```
---
### Project Details
layout: project
title: Cards Mockup project

# Project Extra Sections
sections_top:
  sections: ['section-intro.html', 'section-services-provided.html']
#
sections_bottom:
  sections: ['section-fullwidth-figure.html']
---
```

---

In the **single-project.html** layout

I conditionally include the html sections provided earlier on each document's front-matter like bellow:

```
<div class="main-container">
{% if page.sections_top %}
<div class="container-fluid no-pad">
{% assign sections_top = page.sections_top['sections'] %}
 {% for section in sections_top %}
  {% include {{ section }} %}
 {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}


<!-- Section main content -->
<section class="article-body">

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
  {{ content }}
  </div>
 </div>
</div><!-- end .container -->                 

</section><!-- end section main content -->

{% if page.sections_bottom %}
<div class="container-fluid no-pad">
{% assign sections_bottom = page.sections_bottom['sections'] %}
 {% for section in sections_bottom %}
  {% include {{ section }} %}
 {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}

</div><!-- end .main-container -->
```

Here's a screenshot: https://cloudup.com/cK-_jbTdTqU (everything in between the fullwidth images is the {{ content }}, the fullwidth images are html sections.

Comment: Would you just need sections inside your markdown content? Like `<section class="someclass"> ... content ... </section>`? If it's just it, you can do it directly, as explained in this [article](http://virtuacreative.github.io/blog/markdown-tips-and-tricks.html)

Comment: Not actually. Although I could insert structured html directly, it would still be tied to the markdown (to be processed) and outputted through the `{{ content }}` variable, so I'd need to copy/paste and manually change every html section `<section class="someclass"></section>` I'd insert on a specific page. What I really want to achieve is a way of templating a page completely by using dynamic html sections (which contents are grabbed from a document's front-matter) without the the need of messing around with html within each markdown document.

Comment: I think the way I'm already doing it would fit my templating needs for now, I mean I can build up a page completely by (including) the html sections I want, while leaving each document's markdown empty, so the `{{ content }}` variable would output "nothing". This workaround would result on page where those html sections would be Liquid logic aware, so on each .markdown document's front-matter I'd define the variables to populate those sections with the stuff needed for each project page.

Comment: I think I understood what you meant. But your Liquid markup isn't working right? Well, if the front-matter is coming from a post, you should use ` {% if post.something %}` not `page`, got it? And for your yaml you can always use like this: `title: "Something complicated" ` when you're dealing with special chars. But I'm not sure if I've answered your question or not...

Comment: What you can do as well is using Jekyll `includes` into your template.

Comment: Hey @VirtuaCreative. Thanks for the input. Actually I'm already using the `{% include %}` tag. I have no issues with the Liquid markup, it works 100%. I've created those html sections in such a way they could be completely "logic aware". By "logic aware" I mean they're html + Liquid markup, so the contents displayed on those come from special YAML variables I set on each .md document that belongs to my Portfolio collection. I only use posts for blog articles, for my portfolio collection items I can access them through the `site.portfolio` variable much like `site.pages` or `site.posts`.

Comment: I think my question could be enhanced/changed to something like: "How could one extend the `{{ content }}` variable to build up a much more rich structured layout?, However, it seems Jekyll limits the `{{content}}` to what is is, no more than the rendered markdown/html content of the post/page/collection... So after digging on Jekyll's documentation, I've found it does not allow Liquid markup to be passed through the `{{ content }}` variable, which turns out to be a no way for templating orchestration. Layouts are build with plain html with the help of the {% include %} tag, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this: https://github.com/y7kim/agency-jekyll-theme/blob/gh-pages/_layouts/default.html

You can just replace one of the includes with your {{ content }} tag.

If you (really) want the content editor to be able to select the sections and their order, you have to create a YAML array with the section names on top of your .md file and loop through them.